# Can I stop the page from 'scrolling' back to the top when a user clicks on a tab (with Rails not Javascript)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scroll, tabs

Ive built a webpage with 'tabs' using rails. When a user clicks a tab, a new page loads. I want to format it so the tabs are always in the same place on the page as a user clicks them. This happens as long as the user has not scrolled down on the page.  If a user has scrolled down, clicking on the tab will refresh the page and it is no longer scrolled down - which make clicking the tabs look bad.  Is there a way to keep the spot on the page where the user has scrolled down, without using Javascript?  If it must be done with Javascript, any suggestions?
T
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100526-xtrn2ncbetj6bs1a2s4xwywfjh.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100526-xtrn2ncbetj6bs1a2s4xwywfjh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript, nope. If they were at an exact location, you would be good to go, using an anchor (`example.html#anchor`), but since you don't know the exact location, you're pretty much out of luck.

So sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you will need a small amount of Javascript and some CSS hiding.

Suppose these are your tabs:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#content1">Content 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#content2">Content 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And suppose this is your content:

```
<div id="content" class="content1">
  <div id="content1">
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <p>This is my content.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content2">
    <h1>More content</h1>
    <p>This is my other content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you would need to do then, and I am demonstrating using the [Ext.Core](http://www.sencha.com/products/core/) library, is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.select('.tab a').on('click', function(ev, el) {
    ev.stopEvent();
    var content_id = el.href.replace('#', '');
    Ext.get('content').removeClass(['content1', 'content2', ...]).addClass(content_id);
  });
});
</script>
```

You also need a little CSS like so:

```
#content.content2 #content1,
#content.content1 #content2 {
  display:none;
}
```

This hides the other content we are not looking at. We set a class on the content container called `contentN` which is the href of the link for that tab. So if we have a tab with `href="#content1"` then we add a class to the content container called `content1` and now that content is visible and other content is not.

The Ext.Core samples page has another way of doing it, and they have an [example up showing it working](http://www.sencha.com/playpen/ext-core-latest/examples/tabs/). Their way is more involved than this.